# Can you replace 'whose' with 'that'?

Tags: grammar

I was browsing through reddit when I stumbled upon this sentence:

> I’ve dated a few girls that English wasn’t their first language and it was always a struggle when things got really emotional.

I could only make sense of this sentence if I replaced *that* with *whose*.

Is it grammatically correct and would native speakers use this construction?

Comment: No, this is not grammatical, but it is certainly true that some people do talk (and text) like that, if they don't understand how relative clauses work. And in general you can't replace _whose_ with _that_.

Comment: Neither "that" nor "whose" make sense here. "for whom" is what you'd need.

Comment: @GArthurBrown I'm not so sure. I'm quite happy with the idea that the girls' English is something that they 'have', a bit like my very scanty German, French and Chinese. If you can say, as I can, "My Chinese is very poor" I could also say "My Chinese is very far from being my first language". In that case the posessive "...girls whose English is not their first language..." makes perfect sense to me. It does imply that the girls 'have' some English, I couldn't refer to 'my Arabic' for example as I don't have any of it.

Comment: @BoldBen Those are not equivalent examples. You cannot use a possessive adjective in the same way as a relative pronoun. For example, "Whose Chinese is very poor." is not a complete sentence whereas your example is.

Answer (score 1):

In mathematical writing we often want a construction like this.  You may see "such that" used in this situation:  "... a few girls such that English wasn't their first language". (This is not common in everyday English, however.)

Mathematical example: "Does *n* have a factor *k* such that *n*/*k* is even?"